# MySQL query error in inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I faced an error, I want to take username from member table and image path from uploading directory and my image is is autoincrement.

```
             INSERT INTO profileimage  SET
                `imageid`='',
                    `username`='username',
                 `imagepath`='$target_file'
            inner join member
            on profileimage.username=member.username;
```

I got following error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join member on profileimage.username=member.username' at line 5

My PHP script is here

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
include('configdb.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$target_dir = "../Photos/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
   $target_file = $target_dir . rand(1,100000) . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
}



if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 600000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

} else 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $$target_dir.$target_file))
                {    
            $QueryInsertFile="INSERT INTO imgstore  SET
             `imgpath`='$target_file'";


                }
                else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: The query isn't in the correct order. What are you up to? Share the scenario.

Comment: I want to make profile page when user upload photo his photo store to directory and when user loggedin particular image with required info should be displayed

Comment: Then the above query seems totally different. That shouldn't be about insert query, I guess. I hope, you are using session to log in. Just pass the user id to the query and get the required profile image for the user.

Comment: Sir check my php script for uploading image

Comment: i want to save it in database

Comment: This is simple. Let me give you an idea. When you upload an image, get the image name. There are built-in-functions in PHP to get file or image name. Just save the image name in database and when to show image, put the file path and image name in img tag. Images should be saved in a folder. You'll use the folder/file path.

Comment: Sir can it load accurate data from table coz i save data of new user in registration table accept image which can be upload once user confirm and login

Comment: OK. Then you create another table to upload image with user id. Only when user logs in, let them upload their profile picture.

Comment: Ok i will try and inform you then

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the following to select with insert:

```
INSERT INTO ProfileImage(col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM member m INNER JOIN AnyTable k 
ON m.Col1 = k.Col1
WHERE m.username = 'John'
```

**Note:** The column numbers must be the same.